# Using java export oracle and obtain the status

Tags: java, oracle

I want to use Java export Oracle database, and obtain the export status(indicates success or failure), if the operation failed, should return the reason why failed.
But I have trouble in this problem, the export is success,but the label I defined is always false and return []. 
What should I do to get the true status or obtain the failure details.

---

```
public class DumpFile {
    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public DumpFile() {

    }

    /**
     * @return
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static boolean LoadToOracle(String Path) throws InterruptedException {

        String importStr = "imp scott/tiger@orcl file="+Path+" full=y ignore=y";
        Process process_oracle = null;
        boolean flag = false;
        List<String[]> processListOracle = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        try {
            process_oracle = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(importStr);
            process_oracle.waitFor();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    process_oracle.getInputStream(), "utf8"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] content = line.split("\n");
                processListOracle.add(content);
            }
            int exevalue = process_oracle.waitFor();
            System.out.println("exevalue:"+exevalue);
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        for (String[] line : processListOracle)
            for (String temp : line) {
                if (temp.trim().equals("successfully"))
                    flag = true;
            }

        return flag;
    }

    public static String exportFromOracle(String FileName) throws InterruptedException {
        String Path="/home/oracle/output/";
        String exportStr = "exp scott/tiger@orcl file="+Path+FileName;
        Process process_oracle = null;
        boolean flag = false;
        List<String[]> processListOracle = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        try {
            process_oracle = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exportStr);

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    process_oracle.getInputStream(), "utf8"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("line:"+line);
                String[] content = line.split("\n");
                processListOracle.add(content);
            }
            int exevalue = process_oracle.waitFor();
            System.out.println("exevalue:"+exevalue);
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        for (String[] line : processListOracle)
            for (String temp : line) {
                if (temp.trim().equals("successfully"))
                    flag = true;
            }
        System.out.println("flag:"+flag); 
        if (flag==true)
            return flag+"test"+Path;
        else{
            for (String[] line : processListOracle)
                System.out.println(line);
                }
            return processListOracle.toString();

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String a=exportFromOracle("test.dmp");
        System.out.println("a.isEmpty:"+a.isEmpty());
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

### }

OUTPUT:
exevalue:0
a.isEmpty:false
[]

Comment: the line.split(" ") also cannot obtain the correct status

Comment: Why are you using `imp` and `exp` rather than `impdp`/`expdp` or, the even newer, `rman`?

Comment: @MT0 Thank you for your reply, the oracle commands helps me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by "log file", I use imp export the database and output the log file, then I use Java to read the log file, to obtain the status.